# Django Rest Api - ManyToManyField, Display 'title' instead of 'id' in the Exercises Array

Tags: django, api, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Django Rest Api - ManyToManyField, Display 'title' instead of 'id' in the Exercises Array

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

[
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Push Workout Bjarred",
    "description": "Kör Hårt!",
    "exercises": [
        3,
        4,
        5,
        6,
        9,
        10
    ],
    "cardio": [
        4
    ]
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Pull Workout Loddekopinge",
    "description": "",
    "exercises": [
        1,
        2,
        7,
        8
    ],
    "cardio": []
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "title": "CardioPass",
    "description": "",
    "exercises": [],
    "cardio": [
        2,
        3,
        4
    ]
}
]
```

Serializer (So I want to display the title and not the id for every exercise)

```
class WorkoutSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Workout
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'description', 'exercises', 'cardio')
```

Here are the models, note that I want to display the exercise name for every exercise in the api array, I don't want the id! - That is passed right now! :)

```
class Bodypart(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Exercise(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    bodyparts = models.ManyToManyField(Bodypart, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Cardio(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    time = models.IntegerField(default=10)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'cardio'

class Workout(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    exercises = models.ManyToManyField(Exercise, blank=True)
    cardio = models.ManyToManyField(Cardio, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: How do I make a post request to this? So the api would be like localhost:8000/workouts/2/exercises

Answer (score 4):

You can get this by changing your `WorkoutSerializer` like this

```
class WorkoutSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    exercises = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'description', 'exercises', 'cardio', )
```

You will get the result json like this

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Push Workout Bjarred",
    "description": "Kör Hårt!",
    "exercises": [
        "Exercise 1",
        "Exercise 2",
        "Exercise 4",
        "Exercise 3"
    ],
    "cardio": [
        4
    ]
},
...
```

More about django rest serializers see https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/

Answer (score 1):

Create a serializer for the `Exercise` model with the name field:

```
class ExerciseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Exercise
        fields = ('name', )
```

And add it to the Workout serializer:

```
class WorkoutSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    exercises = ExerciseSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'description', 'exercises', 'cardio', )
```

Comment: How do I make a post request to this? So the api would be like localhost:8000/workouts/2/exercises

Answer (score 0):

Try adding exercises field in serializer as below
`exercises = serializers.SlugRelatedField(read_only=True, slug_field='title')`

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue but and this is how I solved it:

```
class WorkoutSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     exercises = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)
     class Meta:
         fields = ('id', 'title', 'description', 'exercises', 'cardio', )
```

Updated the Model:

```
class Workout(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
   description = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
   exercises = models.ManyToManyField(Exercise, **related_name='exercises'**, blank=True)
   cardio = models.ManyToManyField(Cardio, blank=True)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.title
```

Answer (score -1):

I came across the same problem and now I know the answer:

```
class WorkoutSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    exercise = serializers.SlugRelatedField(read_only=True, slug_field='name', many=True)
    cardio = serializers.SlugRelatedField(read_only=True, slug_field='name', many=True)
    class Meta:
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'description', 'exercise', 'cardio', )
```

It must be `exercise` and `cardio` which are the exact fields in workout (rather than `exercises` and `cardios`. So basically, the answer from Mwangi Kabiru above is correct except that slug_field must be "name" and not title because the fields in class Exercise and Cardio are name, not title.